# Установка последней версии python на debian

Tags: python, debian

Мне нужно установить последнюю версию *Python* на *Debian*. Уже изменил репозитории в *sources.list* на тестовые и обновился, но все равно не последняя версия *Python*. Обновлять всю систему с нестабильных или экспериментальных репозиториев не хочу.

Можно ли как-то из них установить только *Python*, либо установить из архива с [официального сайта](https://www.python.org/)?

Comment: Вам обязательно менять "системный" Python или все-таки достаточно поставить локально? Очень рекомендую поставить "локально" [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads#linux) и обновляться, используя встроенный в нее менеджер пакетов - `conda`

Comment: Cпасибо, то что нужно

Comment: А я посоветую [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv), с её помощью можно легко ставить разные версии Python и она не такая огромная как Anaconda.

Comment: Если вы не пишите приложение, которое будет включено в официальные репозитории Debian, то системная версия Питона особо вас не должна интересовать. [Существует множество способов запустить самую последнюю версию Питона (руками скомпилировать (несложно на Debian), запустить инструменты типа pyenv, pythonz, которые автоматически ск.или бинарные сборки типа anaconda поставить (если хочется и на Windows и на Debian похожие команды использовать), можно готовый deb поискать/самому собрать/docker запустить](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/332641/1321)—вариантов полно (зависит какие у вас требования).

Answer (score 1):

Нет пакета - можно собрать из исходников.

Рассмотрим *глобальную* установку с нуля (без обсуждения таких утилит как [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv)), для гольной Debian 8. Вам потребуется `sudo`:

```
su <root_user>
apt-get install sudo
```

Потребуется обновить список репозиториев с пакетами. Пример списка для версии, отличной от 8 можно взять [отсюда](https://wiki.debian.org/ru/SourcesList). Нужно открыть файл `/etc/apt/sources.list` в любом текстовом редакторе (`sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list`) и добавить для jessie:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main

deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
```

Возможно, в этом же файле нужно будет закомментировать (`#`) строку (если она есть) с `deb:cdrom [...]`, чтобы пакеты не искались на диске.

Затем `sudo apt-get update` - обновит список пакетов.

Потребуется компилятор для C из пакета [GNU Compiler Collection](https://gcc.gnu.org/): `gcc` и [`make`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)). Оба пакета есть в [`build-essential`](https://packages.debian.org/ru/jessie/build-essential)

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Еще есть необязательные, но важные зависимости: [zlib](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zlib) и [ssl](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSL)

```
sudo apt-get install openssl
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

Без zlib не получится работать с zip архивами, без ssl не получиться открыть https:// адреса (и это как минимум).

Последняя зависимость - [checkinstall](https://wiki.debian.org/ru/CheckInstall) - `sudo apt-get install checkinstall`.

Затем выбираем любую папку и в ней будет собираться Python 3.6. Для другой версии, необходимо будет поменять ссылку и имя файла на соответствующую версию. Пояснения по `configure --enable-optimizations` есть в [README](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.6/README).

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.0/Python-3.6.0.tgz
tar xvf Python-3.6.0.tgz
cd Python-3.6.0
./configure --enable-optimizations
make -j4
make test
sudo checkinstall -D --pkgname=python3_6 make altinstall
```

Аргумент -j4 разрешит параллельную компиляцию на 4 ядрах - можно указать любое доступное системе количество и это значительно ускорит сборку.

checkinstall вместо копирования в папки напрямую создаст .deb пакет и затем установит его. Основное преимущество - потом его (пакет) очень легко удалить. В противном случае нужно знать что и куда было установлено, чтобы удалить все вручную. Во время выполнения последней команды вам будет предложено настроить пакет - шаг можно пропустить и оставить все значения по-умолчанию. Аргумент pkgname не должен конфликтовать с существующими пакетами.

altinstall параметр не перезапишет версию `python3` по-умолчанию (системные и не только утилиты могут ее использовать), а создаст только `pythonX.X` бинарник.

Пакет был установлен автоматически, удалить его можно командой

```
dpkg -r python3-6
```

Установленный интерпретатор можно запустить командой `python3.6`

Comment: Что делает altinstall и почему не checkinstall?

Comment: @andreymal, altinstall не перетирает python команду, создает только pythonX.X - https://docs.python.org/3.6/using/unix.html#building-python. Про checkinstall забыл(!) - обновлю ответ.

Comment: >Последняя зависимость - checkinstall - sudo apt-get install checkinstall.
пакет не найден

Answer (score 1):

Делал всё, как описано в инструкции выше. Устанавливается долго, но работает. Ставил на Debian 9, список репозиториев для неё такой:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch main
deb-src  http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main
deb-src  http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main
```

Всплыл один момент: по ходу установки везде мелькал python 3.6. После установки пытался вызвать - не работает. Методом тыка удалось определить, что встал python3.5.3.
Так что если после установки у Вас та же проблема, то пробуйте запустить (естественно, из папки с установленным python):

```
python5.3
```